# Excel COUNTIF cell contains a given text (partial match)

Tags: excel, count, match, formula

I have a conditional formatting with cells like

```
=COUNTIF(A3:H2663;R5)
```

If the value entered into `R5` is found elsewhere, the box will then turn red.

However, sometimes it's not an exact match, and then it doesn't recognize it. That may be because of an extra figure at the end of the entered number.

So my question is: can I change the formula to make a match, if the cells from `A3:H2663` simply contain the value in `R5`, and isn't an exact match?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the `COUNTIF()` function, you can use wildcard characters in your criteria.

If you want to find any cell value that has the search/criteria value at the very start:

`=COUNTIF(A3:H2663, R5 & "*")`

If you want to find any cell value that has the search/criteria value anywhere in it:

`=COUNTIF(A3:H2663, "*" & R5 & "*")`

The `*` wildard character represents zero or more characters.

Comment: This answer also induces the last part: =COUNTIF(A3:H2663, "*" & R5) when the search/Criteria is at the end