# Excel COUNTIF match variations of target: LET solution?

Tags: excel, range, countif, let

This is a slightly more complicated issue than a simple `=COUNTIF(rng,"*"&value&"*")`, as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282109/excel-countif-partial-match).

I have a 2D array with cells containing data such as:

- abc
- def
- abc def
- ghi
- abc,def,ghi
- abcdef
- ghi; def

..... and several other variations of this. **I am trying to count exact matches of "abc", but I want the count to be inclusive of cells containing "abc def" and other like variations, *however*** I can't just use the above simple COUNTIF formula since "abcdef" is **not** an acceptable match. The target string must stand alone or be separated from other text by an acceptable character in `chars`.

I think I've got this one 90% done, but the bit I need help with is combining all the possible acceptable variations of a target "name" into a flat range that I can then check my data source against for the COUNTIF. I've tried `INDEX(r_1:r_8,idxRow,idxCol)` and other familiar solutions that work on the sheet when referencing other ranges, but I'm new to using the `=LET` function. All of this works well when broken out into separate components on my spreadsheet, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution with `=LET`. See below for current formula:

```
=LET(rg, DataTable[[Q14_1]:[Q14_9]],
   name, AU38,
   chars, {" ",",",";"},
   r, 8,
   r_1, CONCATENATE(name,chars),
   r_2, CONCATENATE(chars,name),
   r_3, CONCATENATE(chars,name,chars),
   r_4, CONCATENATE(name,chars,"*"),
   r_5, CONCATENATE("*",chars,name),
   r_6, CONCATENATE(chars,name,chars,"*"),
   r_7, CONCATENATE("*",chars,name,chars),
   r_8, CONCATENATE("*",chars,name,chars,"*"),
   c, COUNTA(chars),
   mSeq, SEQUENCE(r*c),
   idxRow, 1+MOD(mSeq,r),
   idxCol, INT((SEQUENCE(r*c)-1)/r)+1,
   X, INDEX(**NeedHelpHere**,idxRow,idxCol),
   SUM(COUNTIF(rg,name),COUNTIF(rg,X))
)
```

Comment: So do a countif() for “*abc*” then do a countif() for “abcdef” and subtract from the total.

Comment: @Solar Mike Unfortunately the data is less black and white than that. My example “abcdef” could be expanded to ANY combination of characters as long as the string a-b-c is consecutive - which would still not be acceptable in this scenario. There are too many variations of the “not target” condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought about this again and am posting a solution that fits my needs.

I don't need to index a single column of potential matches to then `COUNTIF`, I can just `COUNTIF` multiple times. Additionally, I was not taking into account different combinations of `chars`, I was only searching for the same `chars` on either side of the `target` (e.g. ",abc," when I should have also been looking for ",abc;"). Transposing the `chars` array on one side is a simple way of fixing this. It also turns out that `"*"&target&"*"` searches for "*target*" AND "target" (duh!), so I simplified further, removing duplicative possibilities.

My final formula is below, which counts the number of times `target` (by itself or surrounded by any acceptable `chars`) is present in a given `rng`:

```
=LET(rng, DataTable[Q14_1]:[Q14_9]]),
  name, $A6,
  chars, {" " , "," , ";"},
  r_1, CONCATENATE(name,chars,"*"),
  r_2, CONCATENATE("*",chars,name),
  r_3, CONCATENATE("*",chars,name,TRANSPOSE(chars),"*"),
  SUM(COUNTIF(rng,name),COUNTIF(rng,r_1),COUNTIF(rng,r_2),COUNTIF(rng,r_3))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below formula. If you have more delimiter like space, comma & others then you need to use more `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

```
=LET(x,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7," ","</s><s>"),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),y,FILTER(x,x="abc"),SUM(--(y<>"")))
```

[image]

To learn about `FILTERXML()` please read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) from JvdV.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. While this does seem to work for a single column of values, in reality my data span several rows and columns, which it seems this formula cannot handle. Can you share an edit that would search over multiple rows and columns and removes/ignores blanks?

Comment: I think you may need textjoin() then with Filterxml(). Can you post data with multiple column.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've posted my own solution to this.